# run prepared statement in fat-free framework

Tags: mysql, case, prepared-statement, aggregate-functions, fat-free-framework

I need to run a following prepared statement query in fat-free framework.

I am trying to run the query as normal query.

```
public function weeklyLunchReport($date1=null, $date2=null)
{
    $user = AclHelper::getCurrentUser();
    $default_userID = intval($user['user_id']);
    $defDate = new DateTime();
    $default_date = $defDate->format('Y-m-d');

    $date1 = (isset($date1) && $date1 != '') ? $date1 : $default_date;
    $date2 = (isset($date2) && $date2 != '') ? $date2 : $default_date;

    $sql = 
    "
    SET @SQL = NULL;

    SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
        'SUM(CASE WHEN date = "',dt,'" THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) AS "',dt,'"',
        )
    ) INTO @SQL
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DATE(issuedDateTime) as dt 
        FROM `lunch_status` 
        WHERE DATE(issuedDateTime) BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
    ) d;

    SET @SQL 
    = CONCAT('SELECT userId, ', @SQL, ' 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT userId, lunchStatus, DATE(issuedDateTime) as date 
        FROM `lunch_status` 
        WHERE DATE(issuedDateTime) BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' 
    ) as a
    GROUP BY userId;');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    ";
    return $this->db->exec($sql);
}
```

But I know this isn't the right way.

Do I run it as stored procedure?

Comment: Please have a look at https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/databases#ParameterizedQueries to prevent SQL injections. `SQL->exec()` is already using prepared statements. There is no need  to add `PREPARE …` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Put code in stored procedure and call it from F3, something like this:

```
$rows = $f3->get('DB')->exec("call my_stored_procedure($var1,$var2,...)");
```

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't relate directly to FFF, as it is a general question about what to do with complex SQL queries like yours.

I have had the same question myself (as I also have some weekly reports to run), and finally I have decided to keep the SQL query in the code, as you are doing. I didn't want to have it as a stored procedure, because I didn't want to rely on DB set up (it is not versioned). So as much as I hate it, I have some vanilla SQL code in my app too.

The question here maybe rather on how to test this kind of method. My advice is to put report related queries in a service initialized by a factory (factory is needed to return a service depending on the source of your data - for now it is SQL, but it can later change).